# URL slash '/' get double encoded. Changed to %252F instead of %2F

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have two input in my form.

```
Input 1 value = '02/03/2015' // Both are date 

Input 1 value = '04/03/2015' // Both are date
```

When I try to submit this form by GET or POST method, url in on my vps changed to this one:

```
from_date=02%252F03%252F2015&to_date=05%252F03%252F2015
```

and on localhost:

```
from_date=04%2F03%2F2015&to_date=04%2F03%2F2015
```

Actually the problem is '/' is double encoded in url on VPS which is breaking my sql queries. Any help is appreciable.

Comment: No one to answer my problem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `urldecode()` PHP function before you query it into your database. Like that:

```
<?php
$date1 = urldecode($_GET["from_date"]);
$date2 = urldecode($_GET["to_date"]);
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a [bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39746) in Apache (possibly 2.2.2) that makes URL double encoded.

If you can't update Apache, try to change your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteRule             /(.*)   http://localhost/$1        [NE,P,L]
```

**NE flag means: No Escape.**

Another workaround, you may try to change your date to another format that doesn`t use slashes when sending the data with JS: (Eg: 02-03-2015)

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this by using POST:

```
<?php
var_dump( $_POST );
?>
<form action="55.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="input1" />
<input type="hidden" name="input2" value="02/03/2015" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

array(2) {
  ["input1"]=>
  string(10) "02/03/2015"
  ["input2"]=>
  string(10) "02/03/2015"
}
```